# make: *** [ffmpeg-php.lo] Error 1 in centos 7

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos, centos6, centos7

have installed  ffmpeg 2.6.3 in my centos 7 server .
when i tried to install ffpeg-php 0.6.0 I was stucked. those are follows
 when i run ./configure the follwing is the output.

```
    [usr1@aryan ffmpeg-php-0.6.0]$ ./configure
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
    checking for cc... cc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
    checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
    checking for icc... no
    checking for suncc... no
    checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
    checking for system library directory... lib
    checking if compiler supports -R... no
    checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
    checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking for PHP prefix... /usr
    checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
    checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
    checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
    checking if debug is enabled... no
    checking if zts is enabled... no
    checking for re2c... no
    configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
    checking for gawk... gawk
    checking for ffmpeg support... yes, shared
    checking whether to force gd support in ffmpeg-php... no
    checking for ffmpeg headers... ...found in /usr/local/include/libavcodec
    checking for ffmpeg libavcodec.so... ...found in /usr/lib64
    checking for ffmpeg swscale support... yes
    checking how to print strings... printf
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /usr/bin/sed
    checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
    checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
    checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
    checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
    checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
    checking whether ln -s works... yes
    checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
    checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
    checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
    checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
    checking for objdump... objdump
    checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
    checking for dlltool... no
    checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
    checking for ar... ar
    checking for archiver @FILE support... @
    checking for strip... strip
    checking for ranlib... ranlib
    checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
    checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
    checking for sysroot... no
    checking for mt... mt
    checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking for dlfcn.h... yes
    checking for objdir... .libs
    checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
    checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
    checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
    checking if cc static flag -static works... no
    checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build static libraries... no
    configure: creating ./config.status
    config.status: creating config.h
    config.status: config.h is unchanged
    config.status: executing libtool commands
```

when i run make command this is the following output

```
[usr1@aryan ffmpeg-php-0.6.0]$ make
/bin/sh /home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/include -I/home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/main -I/home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/libavcodec/ -I/usr/local/include/libavformat/ -I/usr/local/include/libavutil/ -I/usr/local/include/libswscale/ -I/usr/local/include/libavfilter/ -I/usr/local/include/libavdevice/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing   -c /home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c -o ffmpeg-php.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/include -I/home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/main -I/home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/libavcodec/ -I/usr/local/include/libavformat/ -I/usr/local/include/libavutil/ -I/usr/local/include/libswscale/ -I/usr/local/include/libavfilter/ -I/usr/local/include/libavdevice/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -c /home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ffmpeg-php.o
In file included from /usr/include/sys/stat.h:106:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php_streams.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:396,
                 from /home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:40:
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:91:21: error: field 'st_atim' has incomplete type
     struct timespec st_atim;  /* Time of last access.  */
                     ^
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:92:21: error: field 'st_mtim' has incomplete type
     struct timespec st_mtim;  /* Time of last modification.  */
                     ^
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:93:21: error: field 'st_ctim' has incomplete type
     struct timespec st_ctim;  /* Time of last status change.  */
                     ^
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:152:21: error: field 'st_atim' has incomplete type
     struct timespec st_atim;  /* Time of last access.  */
                     ^
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:153:21: error: field 'st_mtim' has incomplete type
     struct timespec st_mtim;  /* Time of last modification.  */
                     ^
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:154:21: error: field 'st_ctim' has incomplete type
     struct timespec st_ctim;  /* Time of last status change.  */
                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/main/php_streams.h:28:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:396,
                 from /home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:40:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:366:31: error: array type has incomplete element type
         const struct timespec __times[2],
                               ^
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:373:54: error: array type has incomplete element type
 extern int futimens (int __fd, const struct timespec __times[2]) __THROW;
                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:402:0,
                 from /home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:40:
/usr/include/php/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.h:218:2: error: unknown type name 'time_t'
  time_t                         expires;
  ^
/usr/include/php/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.h:246:86: error: unknown type name 'time_t'
 CWD_API realpath_cache_bucket* realpath_cache_lookup(const char *path, int path_len, time_t t TSRMLS_DC);
                                                                                      ^
/home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c: In function 'zm_startup_ffmpeg':
/home/usr1/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg-php.c:94:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'avcodec_init' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     avcodec_init();
     ^
make: *** [ffmpeg-php.lo] Error 1
```

I cant guess where is problem.I have tried to install differnt different versions for both ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php.
Still this is happening.
How to solve that probelm.

Comment: Are you sure that `ffmpeg-php` is what you want to install and not `php-ffmpeg`? it's not been updated in 8 years, and those errors indicate a missing `#include <time.h>` in the `ffmpeg-php.c` file (before the `#include "php.h"` line).

Comment: That iteration of "ffmpeg-php" (the one in the question) is dead and will not work with any supported version of ffmpeg. See the [ffmpeg-php tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ffmpeg-php/info) for more info and alternatives.